# Slow recursive destructor call in C++

Tags: c++

I am using C++ do represent large graphs using reference counted objects. Something like:

```
// Public class
class Pointer{
  public:
  // Constructors
  Pointer(...){ node = ...; node->counter++;}

  // Copy constructor
  Pointer(Pointer& const other){ node = other.node; node->counter++;}

  // Destructor
  ~Point(){ if(--node->counter==0) delete node;}

  // Other methods
  ...

  Node* node;
};

// Node base class
class Node{
  // Constructor
  Node():counter(0){}

  // Destructor
  virtual ~Node(){}

  // public:
  unsigned long counter;
};

// Node derived class
class NodeDerived : public Node{
  // Constructors and other methods
  ...

  // Destructor
  virtual ~NodeDerived(){ ... }

  // Children
  Pointer children[2];
};
```

There is thus a public class `Pointer` which contains a pointer to a polymorphic class Node. Some classes derived from Node will contain new `Pointer` instances. Note that several `Pointer` instances may point to the same `Node` instance.

I use this class to build up very large graphs with millions of instances, and this works fine. The problem comes when the graph is to be deleted. With the default destructor implementation this results in a stack overflow, since in the destructor of the root node, the destructors of the children are called and in the children's destructors, the destructors of the children of the children are called and so on.

I solved this by implementing a destructor for the `NodeDerived` class above that avoids the recursive call by using a stack instead. This works, but is still very slow, and I am looking for a way to speed this up. Is it possible to somehow avoid declaring the destructor `virtual` without causing a memory leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dealing with millions of objects and stack overflows during destruction, then what you may want to look into is storing pointers to all your node objects in some type of  container that doesn't allow duplicate values and supports iteration, like a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`.  Then in the graph nodes themselves, only store pointers to the connected graph nodes.  At the time of deletion for the graph, don't recurse through each graph node's pointers in order to delete nodes ... instead, simply go to the container containing pointers to the set of nodes in the entire graph, and iterate through the container, destroying each node one-by-one.  No recursion will be necessary since you won't need to "follow" each graph-node's set of pointers to destroy all the nodes the graph node is connected to.  You also won't need to worry about the space and time overhead of a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Indeed... replace recursion by iteration, but it'll need a different data structure. This sounds like a good direction to explore.

Comment: @Jason. Ok, I was thinking about a different storage scheme, possibly letting the `Pointer` class contain a hash index of some sort, but I have already tried out many storage schemes and this is by far the fastest I've come up with so far.

Comment: `std::set` is by the way no option since it doesn't take constant time to find an object, neither is `std::unordered_set` since our program doesn't yet allow using C++0X. That I don't need to worry about the speed and overhead of `std::shared_ptr` is not true in my case. I haven't tried it since it made its way into the the STL, but when I used the Boost version (some 2 years ago), it was way too slow and used up too much memory. In fact, my experiences with the Boost `shared_ptr` lead me to write this class in the first place.

Comment: @Joel: Sorry, my last comment didn't say you should use `std::shared_ptr` ... it was that you wouldn't need reference counting at all since another container would actually have "ownership" of the graph nodes.

Comment: @Jason. Oh, ok, now I get it. Avoiding the recursive data structure altogether is probably a good idea, though I see some difficulties in implementing it without extra runtime overhead. But if it works out, it will probably be faster due to smaller memory footprint and better iteration. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't delete nodes individually, you may want to consider using a [memory pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/introduction.html) instead of reference counting. A memory pool would allow you to blow away your entire graph extremely quickly, at the cost of (depending on the type of pool) possibly being unable to recover the memory used by individual deleted objects until the entire graph is destroyed.

Comment: I need to be able to delete subsets of the graph efficiently. Nodes are added and deleted continuously.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to somehow avoid declaring the destructor virtual without causing a memory leak?

I'm afraid not, more precisely, you cannot avoid undefined behavior when calling `delete p` on a pointer with dynamic type of the pointee not matching the static type of the pointer.

> but is still very slow

I'm afraid that's the way it is. Deleting millions of objects will take some time. You can get around it eg. by avoiding destruction of individual objects altogether, eg. by putting them all in some pool (and discarding that as a whole). Depends on what your destructional needs are.

Comment: You are probably right. I timed the deletion process and saw that time for the deletion is something like 200 ns per node. But then many nodes are also accessed just to have their counter decreased without actually getting deleted. Does it sound like a reasonable timing? The total size of the node class is around 3 bytes.